# Polling only inserting 1 last inserted record

Tags: php, mysql, polling

I've been building up a polling function on my site to grab user posts. And whilst its working I've got a few things to do. Grab only friends posts and insert ALL messages by friends since the last inserted id.

I'm needing my code to select more than the last inserted entry into the database. I need it to ask the database to select every id inserted from the last inserted id, I'm only getting 1 showing in the feed atm, I know this as I posted two posts from another account and it showed only the last result.

How can I rectify this issue? And no..My site isn't yet live, and I haven't protected my raw data. :) Something I shall be doing very soon across the whole of my site.

```
    <?php 

    $last = isset($_GET['old_msg_id']) ? $_GET['old_msg_id'] : 0;

   $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT streamitem_id FROM streamdata");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    $current = $row['streamitem_id']; 
    }

    while( $current <= $last) {
    usleep(1000);
    clearstatcache();
    $current = $row['streamitem_id'];
    }

    $json = array();
    $check = "SELECT streamitem_id, streamitem_timestamp, streamitem_content, streamitem_creator FROM streamdata WHERE streamitem_id=".$current." AND streamitem_type_id=1 ORDER BY streamitem_id DESC LIMIT 5";
    $check1 = mysqli_query($mysqli,$check);
    $resultArr = mysqli_fetch_array($check1);
    $json['streamitem_id'] = $resultArr['streamitem_id'];
    $json['streamitem_timestamp'] = Agotime($resultArr['streamitem_timestamp']);
    $json['streamitem_content'] = $resultArr['streamitem_content'];
    $json['streamitem_creator'] = $resultArr['streamitem_creator'];
    mysqli_free_result($check1);


    $check = "
    SELECT * FROM users u 
    INNER JOIN streamdata s ON
    (s.streamitem_creator = u.id AND s.streamitem_id = {$current})";
    $check1 = mysqli_query($mysqli,$check);
    $resultArr = mysqli_fetch_array($check1);
    $json['username'] = $resultArr['username'];
    $json['id'] = $resultArr['id'];
    $json['first'] = $resultArr['first'];
    $json['middle'] = $resultArr['middle'];
    $json['last'] = $resultArr['last'];
    mysqli_free_result($check1);

    echo json_encode($json);
    ?>
```

Would I have to use `mysqli_affected_rows()`

Comment: You seem to be using both mysql_* and mysqli_* calls; is there a reason for that?

Comment: How right you are, rectified that issue. And no. Its showing just the last inserted post..So for instance, the function collects the last post in the database of an id of 1234 and if since it last checked the script finds posts 1235 and 1236 it only inserts post 1236. It should and I would like it to grab both 1235 and 1236 and add them to the feed.

Comment: So if I'm understanding this.... `$last` is the last post, 1234 in your example there. And that's stored as  `streamitem_id` in the database? Can you tell me what the loop with the `usleep` call in it is doing?

Comment: That is correct. usleep puts the function to sleep for a for a while. So its not continuous.

Comment: I don't understand why that loop is there - it's sleeping for a millisecond, and then assigning `$current = $row['streamitem_id'];` - but there's been nothing to update `$row`. Is that loop ever run?

Comment: Could you fix this with a workaround, and change your first SQL statement to `SELECT streamitem_id FROM streamdata WHERE streamitem_id >= $last`? That should return a recordset with all the new records in it.

Comment: You're right, that sleeping is not needed. Forgive me, I got the code off the net, so I wasn't entirely sure what it did myself. I still get the same results with that query.

Comment: After close inspection. USLEEP puts the function to sleep for a few and then it wakes it back up. But it seems it wakes it up from the same last id and doesn't start the function again. Oh what a mess.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer. If you run the query I suggested, you should get a resultset of just the records you want - can you check that? Then you just need to tweak your remaining code, so that it's inside the `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))` loop

Comment: {"streamitem_id":"4323","streamitem_timestamp":"6 minutes ago","streamitem_content":"g","streamitem_creator":"8","username":"demo1","id":"8","first":"David","middle":"","last":"ward"}

Its right.

Comment: I've added an answer, as there wasn't room here to explain properly what I meant :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I mean is something like this.

The initial SQL statement will find all the records that you need; and then you just need to process them into your json array and return that when you're done.

(I've not tested this code, and my mysqli isn't the best, but I hope you can at least see what I'm trying to do)

I've also merged all the SQL calls into one.

```
$last = isset($_GET['old_msg_id']) ? $_GET['old_msg_id'] : 0;

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM streamdata s INNER JOIN users u ON s.streamitem_creator = u.id WHERE streamitem_id >= ? "); 
$stmt->bind_param("s", $last);
$stmt->execute();

$json = array();
$count = 0;
while ($row = $stmt->fetch_array()) {
    $json[$count]['streamitem_id'] = $row['streamitem_id'];
    $json[$count]['streamitem_timestamp'] = Agotime($row['streamitem_timestamp']);
    $json[$count]['streamitem_content'] = $row['streamitem_content'];
    $json[$count]['streamitem_creator'] = $row['streamitem_creator'];

    $json[$count]['username'] = $row['username'];
    $json[$count]['id'] = $row['id'];
    $json[$count]['first'] = $row['first'];
    $json[$count]['middle'] = $row['middle'];
    $json[$count]['last'] = $row['last'];
}

echo json_encode($json);
```

Comment: All I get is Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_array() in /home/fights7/public_html/rawfeeds.co.uk/read.php on line 82

Comment: Found the problem Using prepared statements and there is no fetch_array(). I'm Using mysqli_stmt::fetch() instead and got it working. Going to test.

Comment: Have you checked that it's pulling back the right data? And that `$row` is being populated properly?